# Make an Array of Methods

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to create an NSArray of Methods.

I have the following code :

```
- (void) showText { NSLog(@"text1"); }
- (void) showText2 { NSLog(@"text2"); }
- (void) showText3 { NSLog(@"text3"); }
```

I would like to do something like this :

```
arrayOfMethods = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[self showText], [self showText2], 
    [self showText3],  nil];
```

but it seems to not work because the return value is void and not an (id). But that's what i want !

The final goal is this :

```
[cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector([arrayOfMethods 
    objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Have you considered blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```
   arrayOfMethods = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(showText)), ..,  nil];
   ...
   SEL action = NSSelectorFromString([arrayOfMethods 
    objectAtIndex:indexPath.item])

   [cell.button addTarget:self action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 4):

Methods are not objects, so aren't eligible to be stored in an NSArray. You could store strings to be used as selectors in an array, or you could store blocks that call the methods in question in an array, but not the methods themselves.

Array of strings for selectors:

```
NSArray *selectors = @[@"showText", @"showText2", @"showText3"];
```

You can then call one of these, say the middle one, like this:

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(selectors[1]);
[someObject performSelector:selector];
```

For the case you're considering, it's not clear that you even need methods at all; an array of blocks would do nicely.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use block and pass them to a method and execute it.

```
NSArray *callbacks = @[
                       ^(){
                          // do some magics stuff                           
                       },
                        ^(){
                          // do some magics stuff   
                        },
                       ];

execute([callbacks objectAtIndex:0])

-(void) execute:(void (^)())block{
    block();
}
```

Comment: Wow This is a great idea.  NSInvocation is such a pain to create.

Comment: actually it's come to my mind when I saw the question,

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to solve this, here's one that most closely matches your current implementation:

```
arrayOfMethods = @[ NSStringFromSelector(showText), NSStringFromSelector(showText2), NSStringFromSelector(showText3) ];
```

And then..

```
[cell.button addTarget:self action:NSSelectorFromString([arrayOfMethods 
objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

(..error handling omitted for clarity..)

Other options include use of Blocks or using NSInvocation objects.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use `NSOperationQueue` and `NSInvocationOperation` to store selectors and manage them. Here is a good tutorial:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-the-nsoperationqueue-class--mobile-14993

Answer (score 0):

You can create C array with selectors:

```
SEL selectors[] = {@selector(showText), @selector(showText2), @selector(showText3)};
```

And after that just call it like that:

```
[cell.button addTarget:self action:selectors[indexPath.item] forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Please note that it will show warnings because selector is be unknown in compile time.

Answer (score 0):

You could try an array of `NSInvocations`:

```
NSArray * invocations = @[ [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature: [NSMethodSignature methodSignatureForSelector: @selector(showText)]],
                           [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature: [NSMethodSignature methodSignatureForSelector: @selector(showText2)]],
                           [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature: [NSMethodSignature methodSignatureForSelector: @selector(showText3)]]];

UIButton * button;

for (NSInvocation * invocation in invocations) {
    [button addTarget: self action: invocation.selector forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a lot easier in Swift, because in Swift when you call `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` what you pass for `action:` *is a string*. Thus you could just keep an array of strings.

So, your array would look like:

```
let arr = ["showText", "showText2", "showText3"]
```

...and you'd be all set. You'd pass e.g. `arr[1]` directly to `action:` when you call `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`.

---

As it turns out, you didn't really need to "Make an Array of Methods", nor would it have done you any good to do so, because the `action:` parameter is a *selector*, not a method. However, the more general question you *seemed* to be asking - how to store an *actual array of methods* - is *also* trivial in Swift, because in Swift, methods *are* objects and *can* be stored in an array:

```
typealias V = () -> ()
var arr = V[]()
func showtext1 () { println ("text1") }
func showtext2 () { println ("text2") }
func showtext3 () { println ("text3") }
func makeArray () { // here's how to make the array
    arr = [self.showtext1, self.showtext2, self.showtext3]
}
func callArray () { // here's how to call all the methods in the array
    for m in arr {m()}
}
```

Comment: Yes, It really surprised me that methods aren't object :/ So much easier in swift !

Comment: And in fact I've filed a bug report asking Apple to reimplement `addTarget:action:controlEvents:` so that it takes a method rather than a string, as this will be a lot safer - you can't end up with a crash at runtime ("unknown selector") if what you're passing is the actual target-and-method (like `self.showtext1`).