# Specific Action for each UIButton in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have 4 UICollectionCell (named CustomCell) with each one containing a single button. Each buttons must have a different behaviour. I managed to do it by using NSArray (thanks stackOverflow!) and setting different font and selector, but I feel there must be an easier way that I didn't find out.

Here is my code :

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "customCell.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController
{
    NSArray * arrayOfImg;
    NSArray * arrayOfMethods;

}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[self myCollectionView]setDataSource:self];
    [[self myCollectionView]setDelegate:self];

    arrayOfImg = @[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"note_button", @"photo_button", @"sync_agenda_button", @"sync_contacts_button", nil];

    arrayOfMethods = @[@"showText", @"showText2", @"showText3", @"showText4"];

}

-(void)showText
{
    NSLog(@"text1!");
}

-(void)showText2
{
    NSLog(@"text2");
}

-(void)showText3
{
    NSLog(@"text3");
}

-(void)showText4
{
    NSLog(@"text4");
}

#pragma mark CollectionView methods

- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 4;
}
```

And here is where i set the different behaviour :

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    customCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrayOfImg objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString([arrayOfMethods objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]);
    [cell.myButton addTarget:self action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: So, what's the problem? Is this not a duplicate of [Make an Array of Methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512507/make-an-array-of-methods)?

Comment: I just felt it was way less intuitive than in android so i thought that maybe i missed a part. Furthermore, i didn't find how to do this common operation on the web, which surprised me

Comment: What you have is fine.  Alternatively, you can give the buttons the same target/selector, then upon press, determine the index path of the sender and branch from there.

Comment: Selector? @selector(buttoneventhere)